# $scope cannot set property on $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

Hi I'm new to angularjs and I'm using $rootScope to change a $scope variable on $stateChangeSuccess. The problem is, i get an error message that says, "TypeError: Cannot set property 'show' of null". This is a snipet of my code

```
    // unhide this view whenever visited
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,     fromParams) {
        $scope.$parent.show = false;
        alert($scope.$parent.show);
        return $scope.$parent.show;

});
```

and the html ...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="dl-horizontal" id="information">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <!-- route veiw, hide the child view initailly -->
        <div ui-view ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" ng-hide="show">
```

Basically, I want to unhide the parent view whenever I get out of the child state. The $scope variable has a value to it and the code works, it's just that I get this error message. Any ideas on how to solve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using root scope, you can add the $on to the $scope that holds the property that you wish to change.

For example:

```
controller: function($scope, $stateParams, carsDataService) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.cars = carsDataService.getCars();
    $scope.pageState = { selectedCarId: null };

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams,    fromState, fromParams){
        $scope.pageState.selectedCarId = toParams.id;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a child scope inside a listener of the `$rootScope`.

Just set your property on the `$rootScope` and, if your scope isn't isolated, it will be accessible from children scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean "set your property on the $rootScope"?

Comment: Instead of `$scope.$parent.show = false;` use `$rootScope.show = false;`